# Problem in installing ecapture in python 3.10

Tags: python, pip

I was just preparing to make a voice assistant and an error occurred while I was installing the ***ecapture*** module in python. I used pip for installing and the error is as shown below.

```
Failed to build scikit-image
ERROR: Could not build wheels for scikit-image, which is required to install py.project.toml-based projects
```

I have tried to install it from PyPI
even I do have tried to restart my computer, reinstall python, etc.
but it doesn't just work.

Comment: You can try grabbing a pre-built binary from somewhere online, if you trust the site to build a safe binary.

Comment: thanks but this is my first question of stackoverflow so, how do i close it?

Comment: You can either delete the question, or accept an answer if it answers your question. Also, please don't use the comments as a play-by-play chat interface. The aim of a good question is to solve a problem not just for you, but for whoever searches for the answer later, and they don't need the chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: only use this answer if you trust binaries built by Christoph Gohlke, who maintains an excellent index of binaries here [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)

You can either grab the needed packages from there manually, or use this package (which I wrote, full disclosure):

```
pip install gohlkegrabber
ggrab . scikit-image
pip install scikit_image-0.19.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
pip install ecapture
```

Note that the package you were lacking is `scikit-image` - you may be able to find binaries elsewhere as well, the site above is only provided as a suggestion. Again, only use if you trust the author.

Also note that the package was called `scikit_image-0.19.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl` for me, as I'm on Python 3.10 on 64-bit Windows. Yours may have a different name (if available), but the `ggrab` command will tell you.

Finally note that 0.19.0 just happens to be the most recent build on that site - it's not guaranteed to have the latest build, or to have the latest build for your OS/version of Python.

Comment: after i installed scikit-image 1.19.0 succesfully, i tried to run pip install ecapture but ecapture needs scikit-image 1.14.2 and from pip and pypi, it shows the same error. how do i get over it?

Comment: That will have to depend on what else is in your environment - I performed the above steps in a clean virtual environment on 64-bit Windows 10 and Python 3.10 without a hitch. If you're on the same platform, I'd suggest trying in a new virtual environment and if that works, adding in what else you need to find the conflict (if there is any)

Comment: I added the module to a fresh virtual environment and it do worked! Thanks